# Angularjs dynamic binding ng-click without directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have a service that creates popups on demand, there's no template since everything is dynamically generated when a notification is received:

```
message = "<a ng-click=\"openModal(msg.type, msg.id)\">" + msg.content + "</a>";
popupService.showMessage(message);
```

I need to bind a function to the message link, so when the message is clicked a modal window can be created from the openModal(). By using a template or a directive it is possible to do it, but I can't template it and I can't find a way to dynamically bind the ng-click to my openModal(). Is there a way to do that during the generation of the link itself?

Comment: Where is openModal defined? And what's the context of the code snippet you've posted? A controller? A bit of code showing that might be useful. And why don't you want to use a directive?

Comment: Hi Michal, I tried to make a fiddle but it's a ton of code and I coudln't make it work (yet). openModal() is inside a factory used by the same controller that calls the lines of code I have shown above. I don't think I can use a directive, this snippet of code is called by a registered handler when a SSE is received, so I don't know if it's possible to use a directive in this context. Thanks for helping.

Comment: I guess you need to do a $compile on the message, otherwise it cannot become "acive"